# Upgrading to XCode 4.5.1 not possible

Tags: xcode

I cannot download XCode 4.5.1 from the app store. I've a valid developer license and so on. I entered my Apple Id to login to the app store and after clicking on the Upgrade button for updating xcode 4.5.1 the button's text switches from "Upgrade" to "Install". But when clicking again on install nothing happens. So the situtation I'm ending up with is that I can click on the Install button but nothing ever happens...

Currently I'm running XCode Version 4.4 (4F250) on my Mac OS Lion Version 10.7.5.

Comment: Why? Does XCode 4.5.1 require Mountain Lion?

Comment: According to the web site, it doesn't. But it probably makes things easier.

Comment: Okay, thanks but currently I want to stay on 10.7.5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, here is what I did:

1. Goto [Apple Developer Download Center](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode) and download XCode directly from the webpage (NOT from this stupid App Store)
2. Rename the existing old XCode App in the Applications folder to e.g. XCode_44 or simply delete it by dragging it into the trash
3. Open den dmg XCode 4.5.1 file and copy the XCode to the applications folder
4. Start XCode 4.5.1 (can take a while, so be patient)
5. Here you go! Now you can use XCode 4.4 and XCode 4.5.1 in parallel (if you want this)